# Read Game scores in Android

Tags: android, api, facebook-graph-api, game-engine

I am planning on a android application which is more like a global leaderboard for all the popular games such as Temple run, Cut the rope, Candy Crush etc. I wanna know is there any legal way to get the scores of the user, such as developer API. Can we get the scores of Candy crush through Facebook?

I did some research on Google but couldn't find anything yet.

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is legal or easy. high scores are probably stored on their servers, or in the app storage.

Those apps would have to publicly expose their data if it is stored locally on the phone, and since they are made by bigger studios I doubt they would.

Comment: Yes. That is the problem. I just wanna know whether there is any API kind of a thing to retrieve data with the permission of the user.

Comment: Not that I know of, the app would have to provide an API and I doubt they would go out of their way to do it. Have you tried contacting the developers of all these games?